# How to deal with image data captured from different camera sources

Tags: image, image-processing, deep-learning

I am trying to object classification of a kind, where the image data that I have has been captured via different sources. Can someone suggest ways or models that are unaffected by the source of the data, but can still perform well to identify the object?

The train images are captured using a microscope, dslr and phone camera. Where as the test images are captured using a phone.

Again, there are differences in each of their backgrounds, and lightning conditions as well. I know there are image preprocessing techniques that I can use to equalize images on the lightning part, but there is a lot of difference in their resolutions as well.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!